# Resources on being a good husband?

Tags: nikah, husband-wife, behavior

Salaam alaikum

Can anyone recommend good resources (books, videos, etc.) on being a good husband in Islam? Sunni sources only please.

Answer (score 1):

In Islam, an ideal husband possesses good attributes and has enough courage, dignity, courteousness, patience, kindness, strength of character, and knowledge that entitle him to rise above any hatred of his wife in his dealings with her.
This is beautifully explained by the Prophet (SAW) in a narration recorded by Muslim,

> A believing man should not hate a believing woman; if he dislikes one
> of her characteristics, he will be pleased with another*.” [Sahih
> Muslim 1468 b](https://sunnah.com/muslim/17/81)

The aforementioned hadith teaches us that even if a husband dislikes something in his wife, he should try to find some favorable characteristics she may have and which will please him, thus it is unwise to ignore the good side of her character and focus only on the negative aspects.

The Prophet (SAW) also said:

> “*The most perfect of believers is the one who is best in character,
> and the best of you is he who is best to his wives.*” [Tirmizi
> #1162](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi:1162)

[Sahih al-Bukhari 3331](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3331)

> “*Treat women kindly, for woman was created from a rib. The part of it
> that is most bent is the top.  If you try to straighten it you will
> break it (and her breaking is her divorce), and if you leave  it alone
> it will remain  bent.  So, treat women kindly.*”

The Prophet of Allah (SAWW) once stated:

> "The more one becomes faithful the more one expresses kindness to his
> spouse" [Mustadrak, vol 2, p 550](https://www.parhlo.com/4-basic-duties-of-husbands-in-islam-according-to-quran-and-hadiths/)